# Linux looks in wrong file parth but works on windows for SQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, discord.py

Hello i am using the discordLevelingSystem and when connecting to the database file on windows it works fine however one Linux does not.

```
lvl = DiscordLevelingSystem(rate=1, per=60, level_up_announcement=announcement)
lvl.connect_to_database_file('databases\DiscordLevelingSystem.db')
```

Where it connect to the database on windows it looks in the files given but on Linux it gives me the error

```
File "bot.py", line 200, in <module>
    lvl.connect_to_database_file("\databases\discordLevelingSystem.db")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discordLevelingSystem/leveling_system.py", line 316, in connect_to_database_file
    raise DatabaseFileNotFound(f'The database file in path {path!r} was not found')
discordLevelingSystem.errors.DatabaseFileNotFound: The database file in path '\\databases\\discordLevelingSystem.db' was not found
```

is there something I need to add to get this working on Linux or do I need to install another library. Not sure if it help but here is [the full code](https://github.com/micfun123/Simplex_bot)

Comment: `The database file in path '\\databases\\discordLevelingSystem.db' was not found`, are you sure the file is in that path? You can't expect for one python script to work cross-platform.

Comment: '\databases\discordLevelingSystem.db' is the path it seems to add a extra \ in the error  @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: `r”databases/discordLevelingSystem.db”`

Comment: In the path, use `/` instead of `\ `,